# How to download pdf using OpenHtmlToPdf library in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, openhtmltopdf

I want to convert html into pdf in java and download the generated pdf. I am using OpenHtmlToPdf library. It is generating the PDF but I am not able to download it.

I can download the generated pdf by passing file name.

```java
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("E:\\out5.pdf");
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.useFastMode();
builder.withW3cDocument(html5ParseDocument(htmlString,3000),"");
builder.toStream(os);
builder.run();
```

But I want to download the pdf instead of writing in a file. So, I write the following code:

```java
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.useFastMode();
builder.withW3cDocument(html5ParseDocument(htmlString,80000000),"");
builder.toStream(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
builder.run(); 
try {
     httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");
     httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
           filename=\"qr_codes.pdf\"");

    httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

This code download the pdf but it is blank.

Comment: Try using an intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream. See https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/issues/107

Answer (score 0):

```
File pdf = new File("E://output.pdf");

OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
builder.useFastMode();
builder.withW3cDocument(html5ParseDocument(htmlString,3000),"file:///E://input.html");
builder.toStream(os);
builder.run();
return Pdf;
```

then you can write this file to response output stream.